# Schrödinger Equation in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to learn how to solve three dimensional Schrödinger Equation in Spherical Coordinates. I was reading a text book and I found that there is a missed step in the solution, seen below:

> The $\theta$ equation,$$\sin\theta\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\mathrm d\Theta}{\mathrm d\theta}\right)+\left[\ell\left(\ell+1\right)\sin^2\theta-m^2\right]\Theta=0.\tag{4.25}$$is not so simple. The solution is $$\Theta(\theta)=AP_\ell^m\left(\cos\theta\right).\tag{4.26}$$where $P^m_\ell$ is the **associated Legendre function**, defined by $$P_\ell^m\left(x\right)\equiv\left(1-x^2\right)^{\vert m\vert/2}\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^{\vert m\vert}P_\ell(x).\tag{4.27}$$

It says that the solution of equation (4.25) is not simple and gives directly as equation (4.26). Can you help me to learn how to solve such differential equations?

Comment: Would this be better on Mathematics SE?

Comment: @Diamond May you please provide the name of the textbook that you are using?

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Sorry I did not understand what do you mean.

Comment: @ N. Steinle Introduction to Quantum Mechanics y David Griffiths.

Comment: @Diamond Because your question has a mathematical nature (even if it's related to Schrodinger's equation) Aaron believes that it should be posted on Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: This ODE can be transformed into a standard hypergeometric form.   Probably the most useful one as a companion to QM is James Seaborn, "Hypergometric Functions and their Applications".

Answer (score 5):

> The $\theta$ equation,$$\sin\theta\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\mathrm d\Theta}{\mathrm d\theta}\right)+\left[\ell\left(\ell+1\right)\sin^2\theta-m^2\right]\Theta=0.\tag{4.25}$$

You'll have to apply a variable change: let $x=\cos(\theta)$. That will lead you to the associated [Legendre Differential Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html)

\begin{equation}
(1-x^{2})\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}\Theta}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}}-\left(2x\frac{\mathrm{d}\Theta}{\mathrm{d}x}+\ell\left(\ell+1\right)-\frac{m^{2}}{1-x^{2}}\right)\Theta=0
\end{equation}

This is satisfied for values $x\in [-1,1]$ using [Legendre Polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html) given by Rodrigues' formula:

\begin{equation}
P_{\ell m}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{m}}{2^{\ell}\ell!}(1-x^{2})^{m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{m+\ell}}{\mathrm{d}x^{m+\ell}}(x^{2}-1)
\end{equation}

where $-\ell\leq m \leq \ell$

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170509204654/http://www.physicspages.com:80/2011/03/22/associated-legendre-functions/) you can see a detailed solution.

I may recommend [Arfken & Weber's *Mathematical Methods for Physicists*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120598760) text.